# Moving hair system with armature control

Tags: particles

How do we get hair particle system to move with mesh as armature deforms said mesh.....my hair moves when I move mesh as separate object though stays put when I try to animate the mesh with an armature.   I could not find much documentation about hair system in manual.  Help would be appreciated with greatness..

Answer (score 1):

Armature modifier must be higher in stack than particle system...also in particle settings-emssion-source check use modifier stack.